# MapStruct generator does not identify different mapping with 2 arguments

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I got multiple different types FooA, FooB, FooC, FooD,...

Now I need to map them all to a "Dto" and in some cases the integration with immutables.org works flawless on that, but MapStruct has the problem that it cannot identify the correct mapping method:

```
class FooADto {
    // foo A properties
    FooBDto fooB;
    FooCDto fooC;
}

class FooCDto {
    // foo C properties
    List<FooDDto> fooDs;
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)
public interface DtoMapper {
    FooADto toDto(FooA fooA, FooB fooB, FooC fooC, List<FooD> fooD)

    FooCDto toDto(FooC fooC, List<FooD> fooD)
}
```

The generator now generates methods to map each type on it's own, **but does not reuse** the second method in order to map `FooCDto` together with the `FooD`s

Is there another way that using `expression = java(...)` to accomplish that mapstruct realizes to use that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You can create a mapper for each object, and then tells mapstruct to use it. Example:

```
@Mapper(uses = {FooBMapper.class, FooCMapper.class})
public interface FooAMapper {

}
```

Open this [mapstruct guide step-by-step](https://reflectoring.io/java-mapping-with-mapstruct/) and go to "Mapping Nested Objects" section.

Take a look also at this one: [guide-to-mapstruct-in-java-advanced-mapping-library](https://stackabuse.com/guide-to-mapstruct-in-java-advanced-mapping-library/) section "Mapping Child Entities"

**Solution 2:**

MapStruct doesn't allow to use qualifiedByName with multiple parameters so you can't use it in your case.

But if your ENTITY has the same structure as DTO, you can pass a single object to the mapper method toDto

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)
public interface DtoMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "fooC", qualifiedByName = "toFooCDto")
    FooADto toDto(FooA fooA)
    
    @Named("toFooCDto")
    default FooCDto toFooCDto(FooA fooA) {
       
        //You can take fooC from fooA, and fooD from fooC
        
        FooCDto fooCDto = new FooCDto();

        //Add your custom mapping implementation

        return fooCDto;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's ugly but it works